# Looping through the arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop, foreach

This is my original code

```
    [Width] => Array
        (
            [0] => 400px
            [1] => 323a
        )

    [Height] => Array
        (
            [0] => 244px
            [1] => 244px
        )

    [Captions] => Array
        (
            [0] => [{ "captionId": 1,"caption": "Learning Clock Face is fun - you learn importance of time.","xyCordinates": "40px-250px","dimension": "70%-20%"},{"captionId": 2,"caption": "12 AM or 12 PM","xyCordinates": "40px-250px","dimension": "70%-20%"}]
            [1] => [{ "captionId": 1,"caption": "Learning Clock Face is fun - you learn importance of time.","xyCordinates": "40px-250px","dimension": "70%-20%"},{"captionId": 2,"caption": "12 AM or 12 PM","xyCordinates": "40px-250px","dimension": "70%-20%"}]
        )
)
```

The above code is my actual code, Now I need to loop it so that my code looks similar to the one below. Please help me out.

The page id keeps incrementing. Please help me out

```
"Pages": [
    {
      "pageId": "1",
      "resource": {
        "width": "220px",
        "height": "120px",
        "captions": [
          {
            "captionId": 1,
            "caption": "Learning alphabets is fun - you learn what to eat.",
            "xyCordinates": "40px-250px",
            "dimension": "70%-20%"
          }
        ]
      },
      "pageOrder": 1,
      "state": 1
    }]
```

Comment: I am already the getting the code I mentioned above. I need to format it in a way which I am finding it difficult. So pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

first you have to format the data in to the structure you want to in php and then at the end you have to encode to json..
also you might have to read the data in the array and create model classes and then encode to JSON

```
json_encode()
```

**Sample code**

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

The out put will be 
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}